# How to detect scrolled pixels inside div using vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am creating an application using vue.js. Now I need to detect the scrolled pixels within a div element.
When it has reached the bottom of the element an event happens conversely when it goes up one pixel more from the bottom of the element another event will happen.

Using jQuery the code would look something like this:

```
$('div.chat-content').on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        //First event 
    } else {
        //Second event
    }
});
```

How can I achieve the same result with vue.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ref` to match elements and get them in Vue, then you just work with them through simple JS. 
How to use `ref` - [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements).
How to listen events - [here](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).

```
const el = this.$refs.matched;

scrollEvent() {
    if (el.scrollTop + el.innerHeight >= el.scrollHeight) {
       // first event
    } else {
       // second event
    }
}
```